# Information Gain vs Gain Ratio in decision trees

Tags: classification, data-mining, decision-trees

I'm studying the decision trees in Data Mining.
A weak point of the **information gain** criterion is that it can lead to an overfitting, a solution can be the use of the **gain ratio** criterion.

May this last criterion suffer from underfitting ? If yes, when ?